# Conditions for proper integrals with DSolve on Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

```
DSolve[{RCS'[s] == SNPH[s] - Sqrt[R2[s] - RCS[s]^2]/b, SNPH'[s] == RCS[s]/a^2, 
    R2'[s] == 2 RCS[s] SNPH[s], RCS[0] == 0., SNPH[0] == snal, R2[0] == ri2}, 
    {RCS, SNPH, R2}, s];
```

Here `{a,b,snal,r12}` are constants.  In `NDSolve` a small shift given in boundary value trick works fine, showing that it is a proper integral.

However, what are standard procedures as a workaround in `DSolve` (no limits of integration assigned) when the integrand is not improper ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementation of Mathematica code. It is much more suitable for the Mathematica Stack Exchange site.

Comment: I don't understand why you expect `DSolve` to automatically just work. `NDSolve` will work for any (appropriately formed) system of DEs, but `DSolve` will only solve certain types of DEs. In particular, nonlinear systems are not necessarily amenable to `DSolve`. Example: `DSolve[(y'[t])^7 + y[t]^3 == t + y[t]^5, y[t], t]`

Comment: @Kellen Myers  Hope not off that wildly. Believe a proper Trig substitution in zero denominator could provide some handle.

Comment: I still don't understand -- are you truly under the impression that this nonlinear system has some elementary functions as its solution? I would not rush to such hastily optimistic conclusions. `DSolve` can do substitutions, e.g. `DSolve[y'[t] == Sqrt[1 - y[t]^2], y[t], t]`, so I'm not sure you're on track thinking that `DSolve` has failed to implement that kind of methodology.